# Exchange mailbox size larger on Server than on Client

Tags: exchange

I think this is an Exchange 2003 problem, not an Outlook 2007 problem so I am asking it here instead of on SuperUser.

When I look at the folder size of my mailbox the Local Data tab shows 4099KB for my Calendar, but the Server Data shows 154671KB.   I open the calendar, switch the view to By Category so I can see each calendar item as a list item, add the Size column and I see about 4MB of data across the list.

My question is:  What can I do to clear this out on the server?   I have tried archiving but nothing changes?  My company's exchange people don't know, they just keep sending me back to delete things from my mailbox, but our limit is 100MB and if I delete everything in the mailbox I am still over the limit until this problem on the server is solved.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I found the similar issue. But unfortunately I do not have access to the web-mail version. So I went to :

`File` > `Account Settings` > `Account Settings` : Select you account in the list then click `Change`

Another way of reaching the same window :

`File` > `Account Settings` > `Account Name and Sync settings...`

Unchecked the "Cached Mode" and **restarted Outlook**.

Now all my Server Items started showing up in the Local Outlook. So you can now delete / move whatever you want.

After that, if you want, again move back to Cache mode using above menu & restart Outlook.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 3):

If you have set the "Mail to keep offline" set to 'All', the mail size locally will be the same at server data. If you have set it to e.g 12 months, the lacal data size can be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

They're not wrong. If you have a 'Local Data' tab, that means you are in Cached Mode. Which means that your computer keeps a local copy of the Mailbox data you access. It is entirely possible for this local copy to be significantly smaller than your server-side data, especially if you have a lot of data somewhere that you haven't touched in a long time or have your cached-mode set to "download headers" instead of "download full items".

It sounds like the size problem is lurking in your Calendar somewhere. The simplest way too find that is to do a [ctrl]+[shift]+F to get the Advanced Find dialog. Set Look For to "Any Type of Outlook Item" and go to the "More Choices" tab. Set "Size (kilobytes)" to Greater Than (for example) 1024 (a MB).

That'll give you a list of all emails larger than a meg, which should give you a good start on finding that one big guy.

Comment: This is the problem, when I follow your suggestions the sum of all the messages in my calendar is on 4MB.   I cannot see the larger item and can't delete it.  I have verified that it is not in the Conflicts folder.

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2013, if you select your inbox and then on the SEND/RECIEVE tab click "Update Folder" It will sync whatever is on your local Outlook to the server. A regular send/receive command only attempts to download new messages and send outbox messages, but update is a full sync. If you have deleted a lot of items that have not synced, this process can take several minutes. I had a similar problem with a 2 gig box (my local was only 800 MB). It took nearly 30 minutes to sync.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.

My local data was showing 10MB and the server data was showing 28MB. My outlook limit is 25MB.
When I compared the size of the subfolders one by one, I found that the my server outbox contains around 17MB which is not getting displayed in my outlook.

I logged in to my company's   **webmail**, and there I could see my outbox mails of 17MB. I deleted those files and yeah, now my mailbox is reduced - in both Local and Server :-)

Hope this helps someone !
Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

The  "TOIS" is the top folder in your Outlook hierarchy. The folder above the inbox. Somehow the messages got moved there. They are not displayed because an internal web page is displayed at that level. I'll leave the deep research to you, but I'm pretty sure you need to do an "Advanced Find" to get to them. Here is a start:

- [Article about advanced search](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/outlook-2010-advanced-search-query-builder/)
- [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289949)